# Using of nested QMaps

Tags: qt, c++11

I'm trying to create nested QMaps and in one of the QMap containers I have examples of my class as value, but im getting a ton of issues and I don't have any ideas how to fix them

Here's part of header file in which I create a nested QMaps

`QMap<int, QMap<int,NormGraph*> > *MyWorkerMap ;`

And here is a part of cpp file:

`MyWorkerMap = new QMap<int, QMap<int,NormGraph*> >;`

I get the following error :

```
worker.h:1:2: error: unterminated conditional directive // This issue appears when I'm trying to include NormGraph header inside of Worker header
Also I have like 9 issues which are like that:
Expected a type 
Expected expression 
Use of undeclared identifier(NormGraph, but this issue is quite strange because NormGraph.h was included into Worker.h)
```

All of these issues appear in one line of code:

`QMap<int, QMap<int, NormGraph*> > *MyWorkerMap ;`

Comment: To me it looks like everything is a follow-up of the first error. There is a problem with including worker.h and therefore some types are unknown.

Comment: Have you tried to use a forward declaration for _NormGraph_ inside _worker.h_? And only include _normgraph.h_ in worker.cpp file.

Comment: In `worker.h`, you have an `#ifdef` or similar, without a matching `#endif`